# Can WPF Thumb event be forced to fire before UserControl OnMouseLeftButtonDown?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have created a UserControl in WPF.  This user control consists of a border, 2 thumbs, and a wrappanel.

I placed them in that order so that the 2 thumbs appear to be a part of the border in the corners of the control.  I thought Thumbs would be an easy way to resize my user control in any directions I wanted.  For the most part I was right.

They worked great until I decided I wanted to be able to drag the entire control to other places within my canvas.

When I click on one of the thumbs the OnMouseLeftButtonDown fires before the Thum DragStarted.  Any ideas on how I can make this work?  I am fairly new to WPF so my over design of the UserControl may not be the best idea.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't really figure this out so I added the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events on both Thumbs.  These events set the isResizing bool to false or true.  That variable is then used to determine whether the user is trying to re-size or trying to drag and drop.

Thanks!